# How can I hide $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php

How can I hide `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` when a user browses to another site via a link from my site?

Comment: Hide from who? If you don't want to see it then don't look at it

Comment: thats a vague question, if you want to "hide" it from the target page, you have to use a forwarder like http://anonym.to/?http://www.example.org

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more information? You want to prevent it from being sent from the client to the server? When going to your site or when going from your site? What are you doing with PHP?

Comment: your questions is not clear !

Comment: How to hide my site $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] when going from my site to another site

Answer (score 5):

You can't, you have no control over the headers that are sent to another site.  Headers are sent from the browser, to the site being navigated.  This means you cannot manipulate them in any way (short of a MITM attack).

You could redirect the user to the site via an intermediary proxy, but that proxy will become the new referrer.  e.g.

```
Your Link -> Proxy -> End result
```

Comment: @Rose: to re-iterate, no, you cannot manipulate the headers in any way.  The browser chooses which headers to send in a HTTP request, the previously viewed page cannot alter them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not only should this generally not be done, but it is not possible, at least in the way you are describing.  It is up to the client to decide what to send in the request headers to a different server, not you.

I should also point out that this has nothing to do with PHP.  PHP makes this header variable accessible to you via $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'], but the problem you are trying to solve is avoiding the client from sending the referrer URL to the next server.

**A few options:**

If your site utilizes HTTPS, then it won't be sent.

If you build a redirector script on your site and use the HTTP Refresh header, the browser will *typically* not send the referrer, and if it did, you would only be sending the URL of your redirector.  For example:

http://www.yoursite.com/redir.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        header("Refresh: 0; " . $_GET['url']);
    }
?>
```

Now, you must be careful with this little script.  Anyone could then use your site to make a redirect look like it was coming from you.  Also, using this method, anyone can inject whatever headers they want to the client.  This is just to give you an idea.  Finally, using the refresh header for this goes against the grain of the standards and *should not be done*.

Finally, Google, Facebook, PayPal, etc. all have redirector scripts.  They use some sort of encrypted hash on the URL to determine if they generated the redirect or not.  If you don't specify that hash and just give the URL, then the user will be prompted before redirecting.  Not friendly.

Look, the bottom line is, there isn't really a reason to do what you are doing.  If you are trying to hide something in your URL, then you have bigger problems.  Security through obscurity is bad, mmkay?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in a controlled (intranet say) environment you might benefit from fixing browser configs see eg. http://cafe.elharo.com/privacy/privacy-tip-3-block-referer-headers-in-firefox/ but this is far from ideal.